# Is it possible to output .XLSX file with XSLT in ASP.NET Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

I currently have a .xsl file which I am using XSLT with to output it as a .xls file and open it with excel.

I am outputting this in an ASP.NET application using the response object as follows:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=MyFile.xml");
```

However, this outputs the file as a .xsl extension and displays the following popup message:
"The file you are trying to open, 'MyFile.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the now?"

I am trying to find out two things, is it possible to output this as a .xlsx extension? Because when I try to do that and change the content type it simply doesn't allow me to open the file until I set the extension back to .xls.

The second, is how do you get rid of that message by making changes to the code? I have found a few responses that simply instruct you to change settings such as here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948615

However the client requests the error message not be displayed at all. Any help is appreciated here, thanks.

Comment: .xlsx files aren't straight XML docs either. They're zipped archives of XML. I think you're going to need to post the surrounding code where you generate the file.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense as to why I couldn't get that file to open with excel! Anyways I guess something must be done to suppress this error but I can't find anyone who has done this successfully =/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What sort of XML format are you making?

Comment: can you give an example of the file you are trying to convert?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use XSLT to try to produce an XLSX file, because it's not a simple XML file, as someone has said. You can use NPOI to create pure XLS files, ExcelPackage or ClosedXML to produce XLSX files. More work, but it's actually doable.

Answer (score 0):

I found some interesting information out about how the .XML file extension can be handled. It seems that you can flag an XML file to be associated with Excel, which will cause that individual XML file to be opened with Excel by the Microsoft XML Editor.

Comment: May I know whether you could output .xlsx file with xslt? As my project is using xlst to export .xls file and now it needs to upgrade from .xls to .xlsx. Thank you very much.